# Need unicode support for a regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression `/^[A-Z][A-Za-z.'\- ]+$/` for checking a name.

So when I type George or George Harris or George-Harris its OK.  The problem is that it doesn't match names, words in my language (greek)

How can I add unicode support to this regular expression?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Example:_Regular_expression_and_Unicode_characters

Comment: Google "unicode regex javascript", you'll find some plugins. But I must admit that I never found one really well working.

Answer (score 1):

There is [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) library that adds support for character classes and other things missing from JS implementation of regular expressions. I think you'll find its [Unicode addon](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode) particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unicode to match greek letters. [Here's a map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Greek_in_Unicode) of the greek characters in unicode. `/[A-Z]/i` would translate `/[\u03B1-\u03C9]/i` if I understand right. So for greek characters (and, in my country, diacritics), you need to know their unicode equivalent and use them as `\uxxxx` in regular expressions.

In my experience, if the javascript file is saved as utf-8 and the webpage that uses it is utf-8, you can use such characters directly. So something like `/α/.test('α200β')` works in such a setup.